# "Merge" new file in trunk into a branch

Tags: svn, merge

This should be trivial and obvious but I can't find any examples of this. (I'm certain that's because I'm just searching for the wrong words.)

I need to merge a file from the trunk of my repository down into a branch. The file is new in the trunk, and not yet in the branch; therefore, the normal way that I know to do a merge just doesn't work.  Thus, I need to get that new file into the branch somehow.

I need to do this selectively with particular files; in other words I don't want to merge down the whole trunk, and I can't even merge a whole changelist.

Thanks for any suggestions.

*edit* — I realize I can just *copy* the file from my trunk workspace and `svn add` it to the branch, but I don't think that's the "right" way to do this.

Comment: did you tried to merge only revision that introduced that file ? if of course it was the only one file ...

Comment: No, the checkin in the trunk contained a lot of stuff I can't merge into the branch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like `svn cp ^/trunk/file1 ^/branches/mybranch/file1` to copy individual files from the trunk to the branch.

Comment: Wow that certainly does *something*.  Also if I could upvote twice I would for that "^" trick - I'm guessing that means something like "the obvious repository host" for an appropriate meaning of "obvious"?

Comment: This seems wrong, it will create a conflict when you later try to do a merge between trunk and mybranch.

Comment: I agree that could be a concern, but OP explicitly said "I can't even merge a whole changelist", so I'm not sure what other alternative there is here.

Answer (score 0):

The following command, ignores any conflicts, overwrites old files and adds new files:
Go to TRUNK directory and merge from BRANCH:

svn merge --accept theirs-full

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent directory that already exists in the target branch. Use `--depth` to recursively merge directories and files.

For example:

```
svn merge -c 1234 --depth infinity ^/RING/trunk/exec/parent parent
```

Where `1234` is the revision number to be merged.

New files could exist in `^/RING/trunk/exec/parent`, but are not yet created in the parent directory of the target branch. The above merge command would add the new files in the target branch parent directory.